# C# how to create a method that invokes a delegate to another generic method

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, lambda

I have code like this....

```
var x = inv.InvokeProxy<ServiceClient, AnotherType, ReturnType>(
    p => p.execute(input), guid);
```

What I am looking to do is to encapsulate all of the above code into a delegate including the specified types.

I then want to create another method that will literally invoke the above method. Something like this...

```
Func<a,b> func = delegate()
{

.... 1st code sample inserted here ...

}
```

Then I need to pass func to another method that will invoke it e.g.

```
protected TReturn InvokeDelegate<TReturn>(Func<> functionObject)
{
    return functionObject.Invoke();
}
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean, due to things like `Func<>` and `Func<a,b>`. What's the point of `InvokeDelegate` - why could the caller not just call the delegate themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually is pretty simple:

```
Func<TypeOfInput, Guid, TypeOfX> func = (input, guid) => 
                  inv.InvokeProxy<ServiceClient, AnotherType, ReturnType>(
                                             p => p.execute(input), guid);
```

Execute it like this:

```
TypeOfInput yourInput = ...;
Guid yourGuid = ...;
TypeOfX x = func(yourInput, yourGuid);
```